# How can I delete over 2,000,000 files in a single directory efficiently?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, powershell

#### I have over 2,000,000 (that's right, over 2 million) files in 'Temporary Internet Files'.

This predicament is the result of a scheduled task that runs a script. After installing Visual Studio, it has been generating numerous 'Assembly Binder Log Entry' .HTM files each time it runs.

It's been doing this every 15 minutes for *8 months*. So now there's over 2,000,000 and 8 GB worth of these files in there (no wonder WinDirStat and Everything have been crashing!).

---

#### How can I delete a folder without iterating over all 2,000,000 of its contents?

I tried opening the parent folder in Explorer and simply pushing the <kbd>Del</kbd> key. Windows then proceeded to attempt sending 2,000,000 files to the Recycle Bin (nope). It never got past the 'Discovering Items' phase.

I went for PowerShell next (`Remove-Item 'Content.IE5'`), but it's attempting to recurse through each file and delete them individually. While this seems like it will work eventually, I feel like there must be a better way.

<sub>Bonus points if you can tell me what the heck Assembly Binder Log Entry files are...</sub>

Comment: What about [using `rmdir`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490990.aspx)?  The command `rmdir /s [FOLDER TO DELETE]` should do the trick.

Comment: Not a solution, just a tip: `Shift+Del` removes files immediately without moving them to Recycle Bin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting large amount of files in Windows is slow](http://superuser.com/questions/76906/deleting-large-amount-of-files-in-windows-is-slow)

Comment: I'm afraid that, whatever you do, the files will be deleted individually: the directory entry has to be checked to find out which blocks to free in the volume's bit-map before the file entry is removed, and the deletions will always be done one at a time to minimise corruptions if there should be a power failure. There are disc-caching tools available which would speed up the process, but you will probably spend more time finding and installing them than they will save you. I agree that `rmdir /s` is probably as quick as you'll get. Set it going one night and see how far it gets.

Comment: As a footnote, I am not sure about PowerShell, but CMD deletions bypass the recycle bin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a similar question from StackOverflow there are a couple things you can do. Quoting from the highest rated answer (not the accepted) the best method of doing such as task is:

> The best I've found is a two line batch file with a first pass to
>   delete files and outputs to nul to avoid the overhead of writing to
>   screen for every singe file. A second pass then cleans up the
>   remaining directory structure:

```
> del /f/s/q foldername > nul 
> rmdir /s/q foldername
```

Obviously you will need to adapt this answer to suite your specific purposes since you are deleting a series of files rather than a folder.

This user suggests (and I would agree) the worst way to achieve such a task would be select all and <kbd>Del</kbd> with next worst being select all <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>

Afraid I have no idea what the log entry file is.

Source - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6208144)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> Start > Run > cmd > cd to desired directory
>
> once in desired directory or parent directory type del  (example) C:\Users\username\Desktop*desiredfile.ext

This will delete files without confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off 8+3 file names, delete from the command line, turn 8+3 back on again.  Keeping track of that extra set of file names adds overhead once you get past the first few ten thousand files.

Comment: Can you expand you answer to explain how to do that?